# Is it possible to block ONLY the homepage of YouTube but not its videos using /etc/hosts?

Tags: 22.04, youtube, hosts

**Use Case: Block the homepage of YouTube (https://www.youtube.com) but not YouTube videos (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y1lsbF9NWW0)**

In order to block the YouTube homepage, I modified my `/etc/hosts` file with the following content:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       user-pc
127.0.1.1       www.youtube.com
```

However, adding `127.0.1.1 www.youtube.com` will disallow users from browsing the YouTube homepage along with anything else that starts with `www.youtube.com`.

Then how can I possibly modify this file so that it is only the homepage that will blocked and not the videos?

Comment: The hosts file blocks the *hostnames* which will impact any additional details that are added, eg. the `/watch?v=...` is not related to the block... as the *hostname* itself gets *addressed* as you dictated  (the rest of the details is left untouched)

Comment: Not possible through /etc/hosts. You need your own DNS for this to work and then a DNS that allows for "exceptions" to a blocked URL

Comment: @guiverc I am using 22.04, I mistakenly wrote 23.04.

Thank you to you and Rinzwind for the explanation.